# "Convert" DataGridViewColumn to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I currently have a `DataGridView` based on a static table in `VB.NET`. I'd like to "convert" one of the columns in the `dgv` to a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. My idea was to simply generate the column, insert it to the table and then copy the values in the column of interest to the new `ComboBoxColumn`, as so:

```
    Dim table = DbModel.GetEntries()

    If Not table Is Nothing Then
        With DataGridView1
            .DataSource = table
            .RowHeadersVisible = False
            .AllowUserToAddRows = True
            .SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect
            With .Columns("ID")
                .Width = 31
                .ReadOnly = True
            End With

            Dim comboBoxColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
            comboBoxColumn.ValueType = GetType(String)

            Dim myList As New List(Of String)
            myList.Add("Choice 1")

            comboBoxColumn.DataSource = myList

            DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, comboBoxColumn)

            For i = 1 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

                If Not DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value Is Nothing Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
                End If
                'MsgBox(comboBoxColumn.DataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
            Next

        End With
      End If
```

However, the cells in the new column are still empty; so I thought they weren't copied. But by uncommenting the comment in the `For`-loop I clearly see that they are copied. Could someone please enlighten me as to where I go wrong? Thanks, Tingis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to use a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with only an item named `Choice 1` so maybe your problem is that you trying to set a value which is not a valid selection.

So you have to populate `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` with every possibile value contained in your original column.

```
Dim comboBoxColumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
comboBoxColumn.ValueType = GetType(String)

DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, comboBoxColumn)

For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    If Not IsNothing(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value) Then
        comboBoxColumn.Items.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString)
    End If
Next i

For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    If Not DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value Is Nothing Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
    End If
Next i
```

Please also note that row index start from 0.

Comment: Okay, thanks, will try! About the indexing, the table that's input actually has the names of the columns as entries (not my code originally).

Comment: Hi again Tezzo, it seems as though this did not solve my problem. The selectable items have been updated, however the "selected value" in the column hasn't, i.e. still empty.

Answer (score 0):

tezzo's solution works if you simply add

```
comboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "<Your column name goes here>"
```

when creating the column. And you don't even have to loop over the rows and manually set the values.